# Why are my values repeating when information is being inserted?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, active-directory

I'm creating a script that goes through the Active directory and then searches for information based on another query when the information is entered and there is no information from the active directory the information from the last entered area enters into that SQL row even if there is no information for that site. Should I create an if else statement within one of the foreach loop to fix this problem?

```
while($rows.Read()){
    $SITEINFO = $rows['ActiveDirectoryOU']

        $ADARRAY= Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $SITEINFO | Get-ADUser -Properties ('Mail') 

    ForEach($OBJECT in $ADARRAY){ 

        $NAME = $OBJECT.Name 
        $USER = $OBJECT.SamAccountName
        $EMAIL = $OBJECT.Mail
        $SITECODE = $SITEINFO

        $INSERT = "INSERT INTO $TABLE VALUES ('$USER','$SITECODE','$EMAIL', '$NAME');"
            $SQL = $SQLCON.CreateCommand() 
            $SQL.CommandText = $INSERT    
            $SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        } 
      }
    }

$SQLCONN.Close()
```

Comment: What data type is the ActiveDirectoryOU field?

Comment: ActiveDirectoryOU data type is varchar

Comment: Why are you trying to ForEach a string?

Comment: It's going over the data. Is that the wrong syntax? Should I not foreach a string? and that foreach loop is to change the data from that string to another value. IE from THIS SITE - 0001 to just 0001

Comment: I removed the foreach loop because it didn't do anything for the problem, but the values are still repeating in areas they shouldn't

Comment: Memory persistence would be my first guess. Set the values to $null or an empty string after the insert to check that.

Comment: like @EBGreen said it's probably something with scope.  Before you do `$NAME = $OBJECT.Name ` set `$NAME = ''`  And then if you need to before your insert check to see if any of those values are simply `''` and skip them.  You probably have some rows in your array that are just blank which is causing this.

Comment: Are you saying to set the value to an empty value inside the foreach loop or before it? @sniperd

Comment: Nvm got it. Thanks for the input